# Query config file value on deployed cluster K8S

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I got admin rights on our cluster and I want to query the config yaml file which is deployed to the cluster, the file is already applied to the cluster and I want to query the file values of `networkPolicy` I mean **all** files with kind `kind: NetworkPolicy` , is it possible to do it from the **terminal** ?

In small cluster I can do 
`kubectl get deploy --all-namespaces -o yaml > dep.yaml`
but in big cluster there is a lot of file/data ....

Comment: You mean, getting all the NetworkPolicy resources in the cluster?

Comment: @weibeld - yes this is what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the YAML manifests of all NetworkPolicy resources in the cluster:

```
kubectl get netpol --all-namespaces -o yaml
```

If you need only some of them, you can filter based on label values or field values with the `-l/--selector` and `--field-selector` options.